# Deriving the 'simple-form' of Sackur Tetrode equation

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I want entropy as a function of pressure and volume for an ideal gas. So, for that, I found a simple expression for the Sackur-tetrode equation by knzhou [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/584128/236734). It goes as follows:

$$S = n C_v \ln \frac{PV^{\gamma} }{n^{\gamma} } +C$$

I tried recreating this formula from the state function expression of entropy given but I can not reach the expression which he has written.

---

To start, I multiplied the first law by $ \frac{1}{T}$ , integrate and isolated from entropy which gave me:

$$ S = nC_v \ln T + n R \ln V +C$$

Where $C$ is some constant.

Now, I make the follow subtitutions:

$$ \frac{PV}{nR} = T$$

And,

$$ R = C_v( \gamma-1)$$

Which gives me:

$$S=nC_v \ln\frac{PV}{nR}+nC_v \ln V^{\gamma-1}+C$$

With, $ R = C_v ( \gamma-1)$ which gives:

$$ S = n C_v \ln \frac{PV^{\gamma}}{n}  - nC_v \ln R +C$$

The constant terms absorbed into one gives:

$$ S = nC_v \ln \frac{ PV^{\gamma}}{n} +C'$$

But I'm still off by a factor of $ \frac{1}{n^{\gamma-1} } $ .. did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Your result is correct.  Plus, since n is constant, $-nCv\ln{}n$ can be absorbed into C'

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Your derivation can't tell how the entropy depends on $n$, because you used an expression for entropy that assumes $n$ is constant. As an analogy, if you also assumed the volume was constant, then you would have gotten $S = n C_V \log T + C$. That's correct as long as you understand that the constant missed is an arbitrary function of volume and $n$. And in your derivation, where you neglect changes in $n$, the constant you missed is an arbitrary function of $n$.

Comment: In order to get the dependence on $n$, you have to include the $(\mu/T) dN$ term in $dS$. Or, just use the fact that the entropy is extensive.